# go-tdlib how to use SearchContacts

Tags: go, tdlib

I want to search for an unknown user based on the username.

I am using the `SearchContacts` method from [this](https://github.com/Arman92/go-tdlib) library. Based on the method signature, the first argument should be a `string` that represents the query. Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation on how the query has to be formatted.

Below you can find my code snippet:

```
contacts, err := telegramClient.SearchContacts(fmt.Sprintf("username=%s", username), 1)
```

Comment: Have you tried just providing the search string? `SearchContacts(username, 1)`

Comment: Yes i have. The `contacts` struct has no users:
`&{tdCommon:{Type:users Extra:HnHNClFZNDaAGFQBZFpRcvMGyaLLJhdx} TotalCount:0 UserIDs:[]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation:

```golang
// SearchContacts Searches for the specified query in the first names, last names
// and usernames of the known user contacts
// @param query Query to search for; may be empty to return all contacts
// @param limit The maximum number of users to be returned
func (client *Client) SearchContacts(query string, limit int32) (*Users, error) {
    // ...
}
```

It looks like that function does not search for unknown users, but only for `known user contacts`.

It does not look like there is a method to search for unknown users.

Comment: Oh. Yes you are right.
So, valid solution for search users by username it's use method `SearchChats`.
`chats, err := telegramClient.SearchChats(username, 1)`
After that slice `chats.ChatIDs` will contains id of needed user.